# How to pull all repo's from a page using Git REST API

Tags: java, api, rest, github

I am accessing repo data by team using https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/teams/TEAM/repos. However, the team has over 30 repos and the API only pulls the first 30 repos. How can I fix this issue and have my application pull all the repos, even if they are on the next page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GitHub API is using pagination by default and limits the values to 30 results. Using the **per_page** parameter in your request, you can fetch more results if needed.

Here's the extract from their documentation which explains how to use it:

> Pagination
> Requests that return multiple items will be paginated to 30 items by default. You can specify further pages with the page parameter. For some resources, you can also set a custom page size up to 100 with the per_page parameter. Note that for technical reasons not all endpoints respect the per_page parameter, see events for example.
>
> $ curl 'https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=2&per_page=100'
> Note that page numbering is 1-based and that omitting the page parameter will return the first page.

Comment: Awesome! What if a team has over 100 repos? How would I access the rest of them? Edit: I realized the page=num section, so that works out. Thanks!